# required tags, can be in random order, must only appear once

Tags: xml, dtd

I want to define a DTD for an XML file as the following :

`item` tag contains `title` tag, `link` tag and `description` tag; these tags are required, must appear only once, but they can be in any order. The `author` tag and `pubDate` tag are optional.

in my DTD I wrote as the following :

```
<!ELEMENT item (title | link | description | author? | pubDate?)*>
```

but this means that `title` tag, `link` tag and `description` tag can appear more than once.

and if I wrote as the following :

```
<!ELEMENT item (title | link | description | author? | pubDate?)>
```

I'd be obliged to choose between `title` tag, `link` tag and `description` tag.

and if I write as the following :

```
<!ELEMENT item (title, link, description, author?, pubDate?)>
```

I'll have to respect the order.

so how can I write my DTD ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't a good shorthand for expressing that elements can be in any order in a DTD, so you have to write out all the combinations of `title`, `link`, and `description` and combine them in subsequences (a sequence within a sequence) separated by `|`, which functions :

```
<!ELEMENT item ( ( 
   (title,link,description)|
   (link,description,title)|
   (description,title,link)|
   (title,description,link)|
   (description,link,title)|
   (link,title,description) ), author?, pubDate?)>
```

If you want the `author` and `pubDate` also to appear anywhere, you're going to have to create all the possible combinations of the five tags (!).

Answer (score 0):

i-alarmed-alien is correct that you need to specify all of the combinations of possible content models, but the example given is not [deterministic](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#determinism). This means that the XML processor cannot know which model is being matched without looking ahead.

Here's a deterministic example:

```
<!ELEMENT item ((
                (title, ((link,description)|(description,link)))|
                (link, ((title,description)|(description,title)))|
                (description, ((link,title)|(title,link)))
                ),author?,pubdate?)>
```

Here's another SO answer with a much better explanation on determinism:

[DTD required elements ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022845/dtd-required-elements-ordering/7796582#7796582)